# Spring is telling me a bean name isn't defined, when it is

Tags: java, spring, junit, javabeans

Getting following error message in a JUnit test:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'maintenanceEmailSupplier' is defined
```

Full version:

```
16:36:47,707  INFO TransactionContext:136 - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@612e5caf testClass = FeedbackControllerTest, testInstance = edu.mayo.lpea.lsa.cem.controllers.FeedbackControllerTest@2ac71701, testMethod = testSubmitFeedback@FeedbackControllerTest, testException = org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'maintenanceEmailSupplier' is defined, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6303ddfd testClass = FeedbackControllerTest, locations = '{classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml, classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/mvc-config.xml, classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml, classpath:/dao-context.xml, classpath:/envDatasource-context.xml, classpath:/jndiDatasource-config.xml, classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml, classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/mvc-config.xml, classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml, classpath:/dao-context.xml, classpath:/envDatasource-context.xml, classpath:/jndiDatasource-config.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
```

This is at the top of the class:

```
@RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration ({"classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml", "classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/mvc-config.xml", 
                        "classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml", 
                        "/dao-context.xml", "/envDatasource-context.xml", "/jndiDatasource-config.xml"})
```

This is in app-config.xml:

```
<bean id="maintenanceEmailSupplier" class="edu.mayo.lpea.ca.common.ForwardingSupplier">
    <constructor-arg value="#{appPropertyDao.getSupplier('MAINTENANCE_EMAIL')}"/>
</bean>
```

This is the code I'm calling:

```
return applicationContext.getBean ("maintenanceEmailSupplier", Supplier.class);
```

What am I missing?  Why isn't it finding my bean? (Note, getting rid of the class specifier does not fix the problem.)

Comment: Is `WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml` part of your test run classpath?

Comment: Yes, it is.  An error in that file causes a problem when I try to run the unit test

Answer (score 0):

Your provide isn't enough for me, because it may be cannot load context file or can load context but cannot init bean or missing libs, some namespace of Spring. 
On the other hand, you should use two independence environment. I meant one for testing, other for production.

So you should try to move your file below into src/test/resources:

- WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml",  WEB-INF/spring/mvc-config.xml",
     WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml",  /dao-context.xml,
     /envDatasource-context.xml,  /jndiDatasource-config.xml

And change your annotations in test class like this:

```
@RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration ({"classpath*:/app-config.xml", "classpath*:/mvc-config.xml", 
                        "classpath*:/security-config.xml", 
                        "/dao-context.xml", "/envDatasource-context.xml", "/jndiDatasource-config.xml"})
```

Let me know if my idea could help you,

Regards

Comment: Is there a reason why you got rid of WebAppConfiguration and TransactionConfiguration?

Comment: Unless and until I need to make changes to the WEB-INF/*.xml files for debugging purposes, putting them in two places simply means that I run the risk that a bug fix in one place won't make it to the other place.  No?